# Map is not showing using osmdroid ver 6.1.11 Custom XYTileSource in Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, osmdroid

I used a custom XYTileSource to display a local map in Android 8 and its working, but the map is not showing when I tried it in Android 10.

Comment: The developer documentation has info on what has changed with new Android versions. Here's the [updates in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10). You possibly have some errors in Logcat and those might also give some clue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the response @MarkusKauppinen. I found out that the problem is the tile server with https, most of them are not accessible anymore.